# Have TCP server and client transmit data over HTTPS

Tags: nginx, https, tcp, server, client

I have a TCP server sitting on one host in a VPC, and a TCP client sitting on a separate host and VPC. Right now they are able to transmit data to each other using any matching ports, but I want their data to be transmitted to each other over HTTPS (port 443), is there a standard way of doing this?

My initial thought it to have Nginx running on both hosts to handle SSL over 443 with [streams](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html) to handle the TCP traffic, but I'm lost when it comes to configuring the stream block in Nginx to wrap the TCP traffic with SSL on 443 for outgoing traffic for the server, or how to receive it on the client side and forward it to the TCP client. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes.  writing an application that leverages a TLS stream, possibly using the OpenSSL library.

Comment: @David Hoelzer Thanks, I understand how to do it on the application itself with the native TLS libraries and a self signed certificate, but is there a way to do it through Nginx so that I can keep the application code untouched?

Comment: Not unless it's a web application